# What a heroin addict takes when there's no heroin available, in order to avoid abstinence syndrome?

Tags: recreational-drugs, drug-withdrawal, heroin

The heroin abstinence, like alcohol abstinence, is something painful and hard to pass through.
Listen a history when Kurt Cobain and Courtney Love came in Brasil, in 1993, when they go down in street searching for heroin, but in Brazil there's no heroin.
So, come to my mind, many rockstars are addict to heroin, and sure enough, a lot of time they find themselves without this in countries like Brazil (a cocaine paradise where heroin just does not exist).
So, what probably those heroin addicts take when there's no heroin available? Which available (and accessible without medical prescription) substances would avoid the problems of heroin abstinence.

Comment: No heroin in Brazil? That's funny because it has a street price http://www.havocscope.com/tag/brazil/

Comment: "accessible without medical prescription" - so are you excluding buying opiate meds on the street?

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD, I'm lawyer in Brazil, so I know a little bit about the "illegal drugs underworld" here, and, there's no opiate meds on the street here... but, you make a point, it's possible to find a pharmacy that deals it illegaly - however, it's hard to find.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I never saw heroin here. In 2015 two Africans were arrested here with it, but it was something extraordinary (they bring it from Africa) - Even though Colombian cartels try to cultivate it, mainly it comes from the Asia, and go to Europe and to North America... but, sure enough, in Brazil you will find, normally, only cocaine, crack-cocaine and marijuana... heroin is just like a unicorn here... and in the 90's it was even more rare.

Comment: It's not cultivated in the US or Europe either but they're inundated with it. I find it very surprising that it's rare or nonexistent in Brazil, or any country really other than totalitarian regimes.

Comment: "available" legally or otherwise? In general methadone is the substitute of choice, but I suspect not (legally) available without prescription in Brazil either. If you want to go ["the Russian way"](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/22/health/22meth.html) any other sedative and analgesics, it seems.